# How to style my text widget dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I have an issue to change text style dynamically.

I fetch data from firestore database in map like this

```
Map data = {"amount": "", "type": ""}
```

Example data1

```
data = { "amount": "3000", "type": "income" }
```

Example data2

```
data = { "amount": "3000", "type": "expense" }
```

I want to print this data in text widget like

```
Text('$ : ${data['amount']', style: $data['type'])"
```

my style.dart

```
final textStyle income = TextStyle {
    color: Colors.blue,
    fontSize: 24,
}

final textStyle expense = TextStyle {
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 24
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a condition check to change based on type like

```dart
Text('${data['amount']}', style: data['type'] == "expense" ? TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red) : TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.blue)),
```

Comment: Yes exactly what i want. thank you for help